# Can i Use a normal HTTPS rest service for request / response for alexa, not using the alexa SDK

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, https, header, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a normal HTTPS web-service to interact with Alexa. I am able to receive the request in the service and when i am returning response in the same structure as Alexa is expecting! i am getting an error. I am unable to get what's the problem.. the JSON body and Headers are set as per the standards. `I am not using lambda`, but trying to interact with Alexa with a normal HTTPS service.

```
Header: 
  HTTP/1.1 200 ok
  content-type = application/json;charset=UTF-8

//Response JSON which is not been identified by alexa
{
"version": "1.0",
"sessionAttribute": {},
"response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
        "ssml": "<speak> Donut and Coffeee Aussie Style</speak>",
        "type": "SSML"
    },
    "card": {
        "content": "to the world",
        "title": "Ava"
    },
    "speechletResponse": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "ssml": "<speak>Donut and Coffee Aussie Style</speak>"
        },
        "card": {
            "content": "to the world",
            "title": "Ava"
        },
        "shouldEndSession": "true"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how do you expect us to answer your question with this amount of information. At least upload the JSON body of the request along with the Header.

Comment: Added the response which i am sending back to the request.

Comment: it should be `sessionAttributes`

Comment: Hi Priyam, From my experiments i could find that the sessionAttributes key value pair is an optional field.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem with my response codes. The fields `sessionAttributes` `speechletResponse` are optional fields. The actual field which was missing in above JSON response is the `type` key value in card response. Even thought the `card` object itself is optional. If you are using it then you have to have a field called as type in the same. working json response below. Hope this helps the people who are trying to invade the alexa space.

```js
{
"version": "1.0",
"sessionAttribute": {},
"response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
        "ssml": "<speak> Donut and Coffeee Aussie Style</speak>",
        "type": "SSML"
    },
    "card": {
        "type":"Standard",
        "content": "to the world",
        "title": "Ava"
    },
    "speechletResponse": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "ssml": "<speak>Donut and Coffee Aussie Style</speak>"
        },
        "card": {
            "content": "to the world",
            "title": "Ava"
        },
        "shouldEndSession": "true"
    }
}
}
```